# Spring Boot Externalize properties from within application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, config, spring-boot-actuator, properties-file

I want to set my property source location to point to an external directory from within application.propoerties itself.
I know passing command line argument as follows does the job.

```
java -jar myApp.jar --spring.config.location=/Users/tony/Desktop/override.properties
```

But I want to set this path from within the application itself rather than passing a command-line argument. I tried adding `spring.config.location=/Users/tony/Desktop/override.properties` to my application.properties but it doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding the following annotation to your main class where you call `SpringApplication.run()` :

`@PropertySource("/Users/tony/Desktop/override.properties")`

On running the SpringBoot application, it should pick up the properties from there. Excluding the `application.properties` from `src/main/resources` using `build` - `resources` - `resource` - `excludes` - `exclude` in pom.xml would help to ensure that the packaged jar doesn't include the applcation.properties and would force Spring Boot to pick it up from path specified in `@PropertySource`

```xml
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/application.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

But keep in mind that in this way, you are creating tight coupling of your properties file with your application. If you keep it as a runtime argument, it would be having enough flexibility to run elsewhere and maintenance would be easier too.

Comment: Thanks Kavitha for your in-depth answer! This did the job...
Yes, I understand that this would create tight-coupling in the jar. I would go with your suggestion and use runtime-argument instead.
Thanks!

Comment: btw, how did you find this out? I tried looking into spring documentation here: [link] (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html). 
As per the given order, I should have been able to use `spring.config.location=/Users/tony/Desktop/override.properties` in properties file too since I'm not using anything which has a higher priority.

Comment: I'm glad that you found it useful. I figured this out from a little bit of research that started [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot) :)

Answer (score 1):

`spring.config.location` and `spring.config.additional-location` are only useful when set as Environment Variable, System Property, or command line argument.

The best you can do to specify additional configuration files to be loaded directly in your `application.properties` file, is to set the `spring.config.import` property like so:

`spring.config.import=file:/Users/tony/Desktop/override.properties`

References: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-files